# property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope you're very well.
on my website I have a video player I want the video to be paused when I scroll

html:

```
<video id="video_home" class="embed-responsive-item" loop="loop" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" class="vimeo-video" controls>
            <source src="img/video-home-rcn.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="img/video-home-rcn.mp4" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="img/video-home-rcn.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
        </video>
```

jquery:

```
var myvid = $('#video_home')[0];
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  scroll > 500 ? myvid.pause() : myvid.play();
})
```

link:
https://html.canalrcn.com/CanalRCN/react/index-new-v2.html

Comment: Check your site code, you're missing `id="video_home"`

Answer (score 0):

usually you must do all jQuery searches after DOC ready,

```
var myvid; $(document).ready(function() { 
myvid = $('#video_home')[0]; 
})
```

or shorthand version

```
$(funtion() { myvid = $('#video_home')[0]; })
```

IF that doesn't work use the javascript debugger in your browser to see if jQuery is finding your target OK.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the link i got this that you need to change to `var myvid = $('#video_home')[0];` to `var myvid = $('.embed-responsive-item')[0];` as your video has not any id. It has class `embed-responsive-item` if you want to use id then add that in video tag.

Comment: You mean, like this `<video id="video_home"` ?

Comment: yes if you want to otherwise with class name its working i have tested this on given link.

Comment: So, like OP did already in their question?  Or did you look on their site and see it was different there?

Comment: Right, so OP is missing ID= in their actual code, but has "helpfully" said they have it in the question.